# Default iOS "signUpViewController" not registering parse cloud code afterSave()

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

While trying to use Parse cloud code I have found a interesting problem that I can't seem to solve. When I use the default `PFSignUpViewController` to sign up a user, my cloud code `afterSave` function won't fire. On the other hand, when I use the parse data browser to manually add a new user, the code works exactly as intended.

Here is my cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave(Parse.User, function(request) {
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var user = request.object;
    if (user.existed()) { return; }
    var roleName = "friendsOf_" + user.id;
    var friendRole = new Parse.Role(roleName, new Parse.ACL(user));
    return friendRole.save().then(function(friendRole) {
        var acl = new Parse.ACL();
        acl.setReadAccess(friendRole, true);
        acl.setReadAccess(user, true);
        acl.setWriteAccess(user, true);
        var friendData = new Parse.Object("FriendData", {
          user: user,
          ACL: acl,
          profile: user.id + " friend profile"
        });
        return friendData.save();
    });
});
```

Is there something special I need to do to have the `PFSignUpViewController` fire this trigger?

Comment: if you think this has to do something with PFSignUpVC why dont you show us the code of that...?